# How to create multiple input fields repeater using vue js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vuejs2

I want to create a dynamic form fields to add multiple names using vue js
sample output -> https://prnt.sc/h6y0pf

here's my html

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue JS Multiple Fields Repeater</h1>
  <div class="border" v-for="field in field1">
    <input v-model="field.value" placeholder="Enter First Name">
    <input v-model="field2.value" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
  </div>
  <button @click="AddField">
    New Field
  </button>
  <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

here's my vuejs

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    field1: [] ,
    field2: [] 
  },
  created: function() {
      this.field1.push({ value: '' });
      this.field2.push({ value: '' });
  },
  methods: {
    AddField: function () {
      this.field1.push({ value: '' });
      this.field2.push({ value: '' });
    }
  }
});
```

I've created a jsfiddle here -> https://jsfiddle.net/0e3csn5y/2/

The problem is that only the first name can be populated everytime i add a new field. How can i also do that to last name field? How can we do the tricky part here?

Comment: Your first input model is missing `1` in `v-model="field.value"` You don't have `field` data but `field1`

Comment: `field` data comes from `field1` array

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It will be difficult to bind both input with same object in your current try, Use like this to bind `first-name` and `last-name` properly.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    fields: [{ first: '',last: '' }],
  },
  created: function() {
  },
  methods: {
    AddField: function () {
      this.fields.push({ first: '',last: '' });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.14/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue JS Multiple Fields Repeater</h1>
  <div class="border" v-for="field in fields">
    <input v-model="field.first" placeholder="Enter First Name">
    <input v-model="field.last" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
  </div>
  <button @click="AddField">
    New Field
  </button>
  <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's all i want.

Comment: Great answer! Also helped me learn a little more with Vue too :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're having issue with this is because of some of limitations of javascript and their affect on reactivity.

I agree with the other response as to the ideal solution. However, here is one more option if you want to use two arrays.

the important parts:

`v-for="i in field1.length"` this will loop 0 to length

then remove use of value in object, set using `this.field1.push('')` and get using `field1[i]`

https://jsfiddle.net/0e3csn5y/4/

html:

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue JS Multiple Fields Repeater</h1>
  <div class="border" v-for="i in field1.length">
    <input v-model="field1[i]" placeholder="Enter First Name">
    <input v-model="field2[i]" placeholder="Enter Last Name">
  </div>
  <button @click="AddField">
    New Field
  </button>
  <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

js:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    field1: [] ,
    field2: [] 
  },
  created: function() {
      this.field1.push('');
      this.field2.push('');
  },
  methods: {
    AddField: function () {
      this.field1.push('');
      this.field2.push('');
    }
  }
});
```